# Sending and Receiving images using twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I'm Interested in receiving Images sent from my phone through twilio and storing it, I will be combining the images and sending it back to my phone at a later time using python. I would like to do this in the most economical way possible. How would I store these photos? Would I need to set up something like Dropbox? I'm new to this concept, so I'm not sure where to begin. Any information is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can download the images from the [`MediaUrl0`, `MediaUrl1` ... etc.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133607-How-do-I-retrieve-the-MediaUrl-parameter-for-an-MMS-I-received-) properties of the message body. These URLs point to the images, which you can download and store -- or you save the URL and use that pointer if you prefer that.

> Please note that the files will be deleted if you remove the message resource though.

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-photo-guest-book-with-whatsapp) about a very similar topic a few months ago. It fetches the images from the message resource logs, but other than that, it's quite similar. Feel free to read for more detailed instructions.